# Why is it that PHP constants declared as case insensitive can be reassigned?

Tags: php, constants

Lately I found a bug in a huge system I'm working on caused by this behaviour:

Consider this:

```
define('TEST',10);

echo TEST; // prints 10

define('TEST',20); // Error -> already assigned.
```

But if we declare it as insensitive:

```
define('TEST',10,true);

echo TEST; // prints 10

define('TEST',20); // no error ????

echo TEST; //prints 20
```

I understand what are the differences between CS and CI and I realise that I'm creating a new constant in the second definition. But I really don't 
understand why is that possible?

Isn't that a violation of the constant concept?
Does this behaviour has any applications or is it a PHP weird thing...

Comment: I don't know if the Constant concept is that well defined, but I guess PHP has it's wierd things, why the hell would it allow case insensitiveness!

Comment: @MathijsSegers I'm with you - that's absolutely ridicules and so I can see there is no actual use of this "assignment override", I bet it was not planned by the developers.

Comment: It probably is relevant to keep in mind that PHP in the past never was planning to become a serious programming language. Nowadays it's adding more features but it's still not very strict in it's ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your first constant (which you saved as case-insensitive) is saved in lowercase as you can read it in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php):

> **Note:**
>   Case-insensitive constants are stored as lower-case.

Means since it is case-insensitive all variants of lower and upper case from `test`, which are != `TEST` in uppercase are corresponding to the value `10`. If it is `TEST` which is case-sensitive means every letter in uppercase it is the constant with the value `20`.

E.g.

```
Test -> 10
tEst -> 10
tesT -> 10
TEST -> 20
```

And a "special case" is also `TEST` if you use it before you define your case-sensitive constant it is still pointing to the constant with the value `10`.

Comment: So... Stored is fine but I can still call them in the Upper case name too... Thats why CI constants are for - but if I can assign the upper case later then the definition of constant is not very constant, why is that?

Comment: @ShlomiHassid It is still constant, since the first one is case insensitive it is for every case of test which is != `TEST` in uppercase. And `TEST` in uppercase is the constant with value 20

Comment: I get you, but it doesn't make any sense to me and I can't find any documentation of this... Is that common among other languages?

Comment: @ShlomiHassid when you are defining it as case insensitive, you can access it with any case as described.

Comment: @ShlomiHassid As it is in my answer the case-insensitive constant is **stored** in lowercase and the case-sensitive is stored in the case which you define it! Means: `test -> 10; TEST -> 20`. But now if you **access** the case-insensitive version it is accessed whenever it is different from `TEST` in this particular case! I hope this makes sense for you

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `define('TEST',10,true);` it is stored in `lower case` but you can access them by both `test` & `TEST`.

Now there is no `constant` with the name of `TEST`. So when your defining it again the value is set to the `constant`.

[Check it here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Comment: I know that and thats (in my opinion) should not exists - It should be all "test" variation (Test, teSt ... AND TEST) should be forbidden for constant name once declared as CI - unless there is some other reason they had in mind when allowing that

Comment: @ShlomiHassid then just not pass the third parameter.